# Explicit Formula for the prime counting function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, prime-numbers

I have two questions. [I'm referring to the main equation $J(x) = \operatorname{Li}(x)-\sum_\rho\operatorname{Li}(x^\rho)-\log2+\int_x^\infty\cfrac{dt}{t(t^2-1)\log t}$]

**Question 1:** The first two terms of the main equation are $\operatorname{Li}(x)$ and $-\sum_\rho\operatorname{Li}(x^\rho)$.

$\operatorname{Li}(x)$ is defined as $\int_2^x \frac{\mathrm dt}{\ln t}$. But in H.M. Edward's book he defines it as $\int_0^x \frac{\mathrm dt}{\ln t}$, which actually is $\operatorname{li}(x)$. So what definition is right?

**Question 2:** On page 30 in H.M. Edwards book, Edward implies that
$$-\sum_\rho\operatorname{Li}(x^\rho) = -\sum_{\operatorname{Im}(\rho)>0}\operatorname{Li}(x^\rho)+\operatorname{Li}(x^{1-\rho}).$$
I have no idea why this equality holds. Please send me a link to a rigorous proof.

Comment: I do not know anything about analytic number theory. But, $\dfrac{1}{\ln t}$ has a simple pole at $t=1.$ So your second definition of the logarithmic integral is an improper integral and you must make sure that it actually converges. If it dose converge, two functions are differ only by a constant.

Comment: By definition $$ {\rm li}(x)=\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\rightarrow 0}\left(\int_0^{1-\varepsilon}\frac{dt}{\ln t}+\int_{1+\varepsilon}^x\frac{dt}{\ln t}\right) $$

Comment: For the second point, this is because $\zeta(s)=2^s\pi^{1-s}\sin\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\Gamma(1-s)\zeta(1-s)$. Thus if $\zeta(\rho)=0$ then $\zeta(1-\rho)=0$. We can separate the sum :
$$ \sum_{\rho}{\rm Li}(x^{\rho})=\sum_{{\rm Im}(\rho)>0}\left({\rm Li}(x^{\rho})+{\rm Li}(x^{1-\rho})\right) $$ For the first point, there is the same problem on https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannPrimeCountingFunction.html ...